# One delegate to support function without param and with param

Tags: c#

I am fan of centralizing code in one place and reuse it instead of duplicate it.

We have a scenario of a method that should get delegate. 
sometimes with parameter and sometimes without.

I can touch only the controller and not the BL. 
is there a way to avoid the duplication of GetLookupValues mehod ? 
(Optional parameters didn't work in that case).

```
public delegate List<TResult> LookupFunc<TResult>();
public delegate List<TResult> LookupFuncWithParam<TResult>(int id);
private ActionResult GetLookupValues<TResult>(LookupFuncWithParam<TResult> lookupFunc, int id)
{ 
  var listOfValues = lookupFunc(id);
  return ClientSideDTORender(listOfValues);
}

private ActionResult GetLookupValues<TResult>(LookupFunc<TResult> lookupFunc)
{
  var listOfValues = lookupFunc();
  return ClientSideDTORender(listOfValues);
}

public ActionResult GetAllCountries()
{
  return GetLookupValues<Country>(_blLookups.GetAllCountries);      
}



public ActionResult GetAllCities(int CountryId)
{
  return GetLookupValues<City>(_blLookups.GetAllCities, CountryId);
}
```

Comment: You can use closure two convert your one parameter call to no parameter like that:
return GetLookupValues<City>(() => {return _blLookups.GetAllCities(CountryId))};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to use lambdas:

```
private ActionResult GetLookupValues<TResult>(Func<TResult> lookupFunc)
{ 
  var listOfValues = lookupFunc();
  return ClientSideDTORender(listOfValues);
}

public ActionResult GetAllCountries()
{
  return GetLookupValues<Country>(_blLookups.GetAllCountries);      
}

public ActionResult GetAllCities(int CountryId)
{
  return GetLookupValues<City>(() => _blLookups.GetAllCities(CountryId));
}
```

Comment: shouldn't 2nd line be `var listOfValues = lookupFunc()' ?